# Flip signal values in verilog simulation

Tags: verilog, simulation, modelsim

I use "force" command in modelsim to force an internal signal to a specific value (not primary inputs). Sometimes, the value I force is the same as the original value.

Is there any command that can flip the signal value in modelsim or any other verilog simulators? In that case, I will definitely change the value of the signal.

Comment: You want to do it using a script? Or just force it? Because you  can always force a signal from the GUI. Otherwise you can force a signal typing it or in your simulation script.

Comment: @FarhadA, I want to force it in my script rather than in my testbench. Because I have an algorithm to do lots of manipulation on the signals. If I do it in testbench, I have to compile the testbench everytime I update the signals being forced.

Comment: @rex if compiling your testbench takes too long, you probably want to refactor your testing.  I find the benefits of testing in the same language (rather than banging my head against TCL) are well worth it.  But then my testbenches take negligible time to compile...

Comment: @MartinThompson, you have a good point. I have lots of test sets. I can write them into one testbench, but it maybe a headache to run and record the signals (I worried if the simulator will crash). But I also need to flip the signal without knowing its value, which means I can only do this in testbench instead of tcl file. Then I need to compile lots of testbenches. It looks like neither way will be faster than force it from tcl, but tcl cannot flip the signal value...

Comment: If you have lots of test sets, they don't all have to go in the one testbench.  It sounds (without knowing all the details of your setup) that you need to reorganise your testing somewhat...maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no *simulator commands* that I'm aware of to invert a signal.  However, if you are doing the force from within the Verilog source, you should simply be able to do this:

```
force path.to.signal = ~path.to.signal;
```

If you are forcing it from the simulator, you can probably do the equivalent of the above statement in TCL. You would need to get the current value, invert it, and then apply a force with the inverted value.

Comment: I guess this is the only way to flip the signal without knowing its value.

Answer (score 2):

In ModelSim the command to force a signal is:

```
force signal_name value time
```

For example:

```
force reset 0 100
```

Or if you want a more advanced way of doing this, assuming your time is set to 1ns:

```
force clk 0 20, 1 20 -repeat 100
```

You can find out more if you read the manual: [ModelSim SE Command Reference](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/courseware/cse2306/2006/Pracs/force.pdf)

Here is the extract from that file:

```
    force input1 0
Forces input1 to 0 at the current simulator time.
    force bus1 01XZ 100 ns
Forces bus1 to 01XZ at 100 nanoseconds after the current simulator time.
    force bus1 16#f @200
Forces bus1 to 16#F at the absolute time 200 measured in the resolution units selected at simulation start-up.
    force input1 1 10, 0 20 -r 100
Forces input1 to 1 at 10 time units after the current simulation time and to 0 at 20 time units after the current simulation time. This cycle repeats starting at 100 time units after the current simulation time, so the next transition is to 1 at 100 time units after the current simulation time.
    force input1 1 10 ns, 0 {20 ns} -r 100ns
Similar to the previous example, but also
specifies the time units. Time unit expressions
preceding the "-r" must be placed in curly braces.
    **force s 1 0, 0 100 -repeat 200 -cancel 1000**
Forces signals to alternate between values 1 and 0 every 100 time units until time 1000.
Cancellation occurs at the last simulation delta cycle of a time unit. So,
    force s 1 0 -cancel 0
will force signals to 1 for the duration of the current time period.
    when {/mydut/siga = 10#1}
       {
        force -deposit /mydut/siga 10#85
       }
Forces siga to decimal value 85 whenever the value on the signal is 1.
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I know how to do that. But that is not what I asked.

Comment: Well, if you check the document I referred to, you will find the FORCE command in TCL that does EXACTLY what you are looking for. You can cheat the hierarchy by forcing the signal under GUI then copy the command from the transcript window and put it into your TCL file.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I think the question is not clear enough. I mean flipping the signal without knowing the value of the signal value. I would take the solution provided by dwikle this time. Thank you for your help as well.